# CSS Rounded borders

Tags: html, forms, css

I have a form that I would like to round the corner of the borders that you see below. I would like the borders that outline the form to meet and round.

> [image]

I have tried the border-radius method but it produces this. It rounds the container, which is what I don't want.

> [image]

I have also taken a look at the CSS `border-style` property, but it doesn't not have an option for rounded intersections of borders. If anyone can help, that would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/vB3m2/) with my HTML and CSS.

Comment: Please include your HTML/CSS

Comment: Surely this is just `border-radius` on the container?

Comment: `form { border-radius: 30px; }`

Comment: I don't want a border-radius, I want the intersection of the borders around the form to be rounded.

Comment: @mdesdev I tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the problem, but see if this is what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/vB3m2/2/

Comment: @IlanBiala `.tab-content { border-radius: 0 30px 30px 30px; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First corner removed because of the tab. Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/vB3m2/5/)**</kbd>

```
.tab-content {
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot about the `.tab-content`, good catch!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is:

```
.tab-content{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stryd3r/vB3m2/1/

Answer (score 0):

While giving the `border-radius` to your container, give it to the form aswell. :)

Comment: I don't want the a rounded corner, I want the border to have a rounded intersection.

Comment: Can you please elaborate `rounded intersection`?

Comment: I want the border to have the border-radius, not the element. The corners of the border itself should have the rounding and look like this http://www.teddybearpools.com/plugin_assets/helpers/images/mce/3_radiusmeasure.gif.